# Sort multiple dictionaries identically, based on a specific order defined by a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I had a special case where multiple existing dictionaries had to be sorted based on the exact order of items in a list (not alphabetical). So for example the dictionaries were:

```
dict_one = {"LastName": "Bar", "FirstName": "Foo", "Address": "Example Street 101", "Phone": "012345678"}
dict_two = {"Phone": "001122334455", "LastName": "Spammer", "FirstName": "Egg", "Address": "SSStreet 123"}
dict_three = {"Address": "Run Down Street 66", "Phone": "0987654321", "LastName": "Biker", "FirstName": "Random"}
```

And the list was:

```
data_order = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Address"]
```

With the expected result being the ability to create a file like this:

```
FirstName;LastName;Phone;Address
Foo;Bar;012345678;Example Street 101
Egg;Spammer;001122334455;SSStreet 123
Random;Biker;0987654321;Run Down Street 66
```

**Note**:
In my case, the real use was an Excel file using pyexcel-xls, but the CSV-like example above is probably closer to what is usually done, so the answers might be more universally applicable for CSV than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of hard time to find any good answers in Stack Overflow for this case, but eventually I got the sorting working, which I could use to create the file. The header row can simply be taken directly from the `data_order` list below. Here's how I did it - hope it helps someone:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pprint

dict_one = {
    "LastName": "Bar", 
    "FirstName": "Foo", 
    "Address": "Example Street 101", 
    "Phone": "012345678"}
dict_two = {
    "Phone": "001122334455", 
    "LastName": "Spammer", 
    "FirstName": "Egg", 
    "Address": "SSStreet 123"}  
dict_three = {
    "Address": "Run Down Street 66", 
    "Phone": "0987654321", 
    "LastName": "Biker", 
    "FirstName": "Random"}

dict_list = []
dict_list.append(dict_one)
dict_list.append(dict_two)
dict_list.append(dict_three)

data_order = ["FirstName", "LastName", "Phone", "Address"]

result = []
for dictionary in dict_list:
    result_dict = OrderedDict()
    # Go through the data_order in order
    for key in data_order:
        # Populate result_dict in the list order
        result_dict[key] = dictionary[key]
    result.append(result_dict)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(result)
"""
[   {   'FirstName': 'Foo',
        'LastName': 'Bar',
        'Phone': '012345678',
        'Address': 'Example Street 101'},
    {   'FirstName': 'Egg',
        'LastName': 'Spammer',
        'Phone': '001122334455',
        'Address': 'SSStreet 123'},
    {   'FirstName': 'Random',
        'LastName': 'Biker',
        'Phone': '0987654321',
        'Address': 'Run Down Street 66'}]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a one liner, although it is harder to read. In case it is useful for someone:

```
print [OrderedDict([(key, d[key]) for key in data_order]) for d in [dict_one, dict_two, dict_three]]
```

Comment: FYI, the inner brackets in the argument to `OrderedDict` aren't needed (they just make a temporary `list` when `OrderedDict` could accept a generator expression and avoid the temporary). This would work without the temporary using a genexpr: `OrderedDict((key, d[key]) for key in data_order)`. Or for bonus points, using `operator.itemgetter`: `fields = itemgetter(*data_order)`, then `print [OrderedDict(zip(data_order, fields(d))) for d in (dict_one, dict_two, dict_three)]` to remove the listcomp/genexpr entirely, pushing more work to C layer and reducing verbosity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), because your expected output is CSV-like (semi-colon delimiters instead of commas is supported) which would handle all of this for you, avoiding the need for ridiculous workaround involving `OrderedDict`, and making it easy to read the data back in without worrying about corner cases (`csv` automatically quotes fields if necessary, and parses quoted fields on read in as needed):

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(f, data_order, delimiter=';')

    # Write the header
    csvout.writeheader()
    csvout.writerow(dict_one)
    csvout.writerow(dict_two)
    csvout.writerow(dict_three)
```

That's it, `csv` handles ordering, (it knows the correct order from the `data_order` passed as `fieldnames` to the `DictWriter` constructor), formatting, etc.

---

If you had some need to pull the values in a specific order from many `dict`s without writing them (since your use case doesn't even use the keys), [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) can be used to simplify this dramatically:

```
from operator import itemgetter

getfields = itemgetter(*data_order)

dict_one_fields = getfields(dict_one)
```

which leaves `dict_one_fields` as a `tuple` with the requested fields in the requested order, `('Foo', 'Bar', '012345678', 'Example Street 101')`, and runs significantly faster than repeatedly indexing at the Python layer (`itemgetter` creates a C level "functor" that can retrieve all the requested values in a single call, with no Python level byte code at all for built-in keys like `str`).

Comment: Well, actually I had to make an Excel file, but used CSV in my example since it's more common :)

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: If it's true CSV (you used semi-colons, Excel uses commas), you could just make an actual CSV file (no custom `delimiter`; `csv` module defaults to Excel compatible CSV dialect, and name the file with `.csv` extension), and you may not need to make a real Excel file.  Excel natively understands CSV. Saves some effort if you just need it loadable by Excel, not specifically in Excel's native format. Otherwise, the second half of my answer is still useful for getting the values in order for use with `.xlsx` writer package; it's much faster/simpler, and avoids reinventing the wheel.